# How to use redhatlinux without mouse?

Tags: linux, keyboard, shortcuts, keyboard-navigation

**Scenario:**

I like to use the Red Hat Linux without the the usage of mouse ,usually we use some shortcut keys to use in Windows and Mac operating systems!

What i require?

How can i use the Red Hat Linux operating system without mouse?
Does i need to install any software packages to do it?
Can i get get any common shortcuts in additional?
i searched for it but [the official red hat site denies it](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/.../Red_Hat.../ap-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumLock</kbd> will activate and deactivate [mouse keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys).